# Will $T_1 ,T_2$ and $T_3$ form a topology on $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X  = \{a, b, c, d, e, f \}.$ Determine whether or not each of the following collection of subsets of $X$ is a topology on $X:$

$(a)\, T_1 = \{X, Ø, \{a\}, \{a, f \}, \{b, f \}, \{a, b, f \}\};$

$(b)\, T_2 = \{X, Ø, \{a, b, f \}, \{a, b, d\}, \{a, b, d, f \}\};$

$(c)\, T_3 = \{X, Ø, \{f \}, \{e, f \}, \{a, f \}\}.$

My attempt :  I think $T_2$  and $T_ 3 $ will not topology on $X$

because in $T_2$ we have $\{a, b, f \} \cap \{a, b, d\}= \{ a, b\} \notin T_2$

and $T_3$ we have $\{e, f \}\cup \{a, f \}= \{ e, a, f\} \notin  T_3$

Is it true?

Comment: Yes, those assertions are true.

Comment: thanks u @Gae.S. then $T_1$ will form topology on $X$ . Am i right ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

$T_1$ will also not be a topology on $X$ since $\{a,f\} \cap \{b,f\} =\{f\}\notin T_1.$